# Python Pip "Fatal Error in Launcher" and other issues with updating pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install `Pyinstaller` to my computer using pip to convert a python file into a `.exe file`. When I try to install it, Command Prompt gives me the following error :

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
> '"c:\python27\python.exe"  "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe" install
> pyinstaller': The system cannot find the file specified.

I've done some looking online and tried just about everything I've found this far and I'm at a loss. I have tried:
using `python - m pip install xxxx`
updating pip
reverting back to a previous version of pip
using Command Prompt as an Admin
making sure pip is in my PATH using environmental variables
uninstalling and doing a complete reinstall of python.

Reading other people's questions related to this problem, several people suggested running different lines of code like `python -c "import pip.__main__"` and `python -m pip install pip==9.0.0` and my Command Prompt doesn't do anything, even while running as an admin. I assume that I have something fucked up deep in my files or settings that I didn't even realize I changed, but I can't see it for the life of me. I'd be happy to try any suggestions anyone has. Thanks!

Edit: It seems like there may be something wrong with my Command Prompt? When I try entering `python -m venv venv`, it doesn't do anything or acknowledge the command.
[image: Command Prompt not acknowledging command?]

Comment: 1. Make sure you don't have a whitespace separating "-m" as in your first example above.

2. Try setting up python virtualenv first, to better control the environment. Try

`python -m venv venv`;

`source venv/bin/activate`;

`pip install xxxx`

Comment: Oh yes, that was just a typo when writing the post, but thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: My bad: you are clearly using Windows, and I gave a prescription for unix-like env. Still, venv recommendation stands, try this recipe (I cannot say much from personal experience, never done it for Windows): https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/